# Is it possible to select css generated content?

Tags: html, css, selection, pseudo-element, css-content

Let's say I have mark up:

```
<div data-generated="world!">Hello </div>
```

..with CSS:

```
div:after {
    content: attr(data-generated);
}
```

This produces the text: Hello world! - **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/RpKRU/)**

```css
div:after {
    content: attr(data-generated);
}
```

```html
<div data-generated="world!">Hello </div>
```

**BUT...**

If I try to select / Copy the text - only the 'hello ' part is selectable.

[image]

Is there any way to select css generated text?

**NB:**

1) <strike>I have looked at the spec ([here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-css-gcpm-3-20140513/)) regarding generated content and I haven't seen any reference to this issue.</strike>

The spec [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-content-3/#accessibility) and [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-content-3/#accessibility) seems to say that **generated content should be selectable**

> Generated content should be searchable, selectable, and available to
>   assistive technologies

2) If the answer to this question is 'no - it is not possible' - please link to a credible source which states this.

Comment: I don't know exactely. But since the generated content is not part of the DOM, I should say no.

Comment: Fundamentally not in FF: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12460

Comment: In fat it should **not** be selectable because it is in fact **styling** We misuse the `content` element in using it in this way. If you want actual selectable 'content' the use a proper HTML element not a pseudo element. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Comment: I most certainly _don't_ think that `<div data-commentcount="3"> comments </div>` is an acceptable usage either. CSS shouldn't be used to generate content, but styles. Writing "3" here is not considered a style, but actual content. If you tried to add some fancy quotes or bullt point, then it would be a style. Besides, what benefit does that give you over just including "3 comments" as a text?

Comment: @kba what benefit does that give you over just including "3 comments" as a text?  Well, you'll need to add and extra span element. So if this is used inside a list - you're adding a span element for each item.

Comment: @Danield Why would you need to add an extra span element? And even if you _had_ to add that span element, that's still better than adding a `data' attribute in my book.

Comment: If the data attribute is already set by javascript, why not use javascript to do the rest? Your logic on this method doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I agree with @Novocaine. Your second example still doesn't seem like a logical use case. If the variable is generated or set in the javascript, there is no need to attach it as an HTML attribute.

Comment: @Novocaine et al.  In that project we had a (temporary) constraint that strings were to be created only in the markup and not in js. This is because localization for multiple languages was being used and localization using JavaScript wasn't ready yet. In any case, please note that this is *not* the point of the question nor was the point of the question that  this is a perfect use-case for the data attribute. Rather, after using the data attribute in this way - I stumbled over the fact that I couldn't select the generated text.

Answer (score 19):

No, you can't.

See [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after). To repeat what is described there, generated content is not part of the DOM.

In the words of the [CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/generate.html),

> Generated content does not alter the document tree.

Generated content only exists in the visual world of the rendering engine. Selecting is about selecting portions of the DOM. Generated content is not in the DOM, hence cannot be selected. For the same reason, generated counters or list item bullets cannot be selected.

Comment: Does the fact that chrome developer tools recently started showing pseudo elements in the markup mean that something has changed, or is this just a chrome feature made for easier debugging?

Comment: The latter. It's just a way to select them to examine their styles.

Comment: Re: "*Selecting is about selecting portions of the DOM*", **why so?** Why not do *real* select?

Answer (score 9):

Instead of actually selecting the generated content, you could **simulate** this with some javascript.

I stumbled over this [David Walsh blog](http://davidwalsh.name/ways-css-javascript-interact),
where he provides code that fetches generated content.

Using that, you can append the generated content to the regular content to simulate selection of the generated content, then you can set the generated content with `display:none` so that it doesn't appear twice. Like this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/0v5ayz8j/1/)**

```js
String.prototype.unquoted = function() {
  return this.replace(/(^['"])|(['"]$)/g, '')
}

var element = document.getElementById('div1');

var content = window.getComputedStyle(
  element, ':after'
).getPropertyValue('content');

element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + content.unquoted();

console.log(content.unquoted());
```

```css
div:after {
  content: attr(data-generated);
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" data-generated=" world!">Hello</div>
```

### So why would you ever want to do something like that?

Well, you'd probably never want to do this, but I left a long comment on the question explaining a particular constraint that I once had, where this could have been a solution.

**NB:** I do realize that this 'solution' doesn't really select the generated content itself, but decided to post this answer in case somebody out there ever needed a workaround.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do something like that? Well, a solid use case would be copying Markdown code generated (from HTML) by a CSS template to paste it in a textarea with Markdown support. See https://gist.github.com/ImJasonH/c00cdd7aece6945fb8ea.

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: Use case?  Color value is stored in a variable in CSS.  Value is displayed to the user via generated content (:after).  The user should be able to select that value and copy to clipboard.  Voila!

Answer (score 4):

Do not store content that should be visible and accessible in `data` attributes, because assistive technology may not access them

Check These links :

http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/08/26/css-generated-content-is-not-content/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @trejder a link in the answer does not turn it into a link only answer, even if it's short.

Comment: With all due respect, the text in this answer is about accessibility, which however useful is not related to, or an answer to, the question. The second link provides general information about data attributes, presumably also for the benefit of the comments at the bottom about accessibility. This information about accessibility belongs in a comment. The first link does address the question, the only part of the answer which does so, but provides no summary of its key points. which could indeed be considered to make it a link-only answer.