# Select text in ::before or ::after pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, dom

Look this very simple code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p::before {
    content: "Before - ";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Bye</p>   
</body>
</html>
```

Css adds `¨Before -"` at the start of every `<P>` and renders like this

[image]

If you use your mouse to select the text (for copy paste) you can select the original text, but not the Before or Aftter text added by css.

[image]

I have a very specific requirement where I need to allow users to select with the mosue the Before text. How would you do it?

Comment: No you can't. That's what the phrase "pseudo" means.

Comment: Asked and answered, more than once. See [Is it possible to select css generated content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385171/is-it-possible-to-select-css-generated-content)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't, the before and after pseudo classes are not meant to be used for that purpose.

Answer (score 17):

This cannot be done within an HTML page, but as a hack, if you need to copy/paste pseudo elements, you can export the page to PDF and copy from it. In Chrome, for example, you can copy page's content from print preview.

Answer (score 4):

If users need to select the generated text, it should be considered content (and in the HTML), not presentation (and hidden in the CSS).

Don't use `::before` or `::after`, use HTML.

You could use JavaScript to insert it (if that would help):

```
var text = document.createTextNode('Before - ');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('p'), function (p) {
    p.insertBefore(text.cloneNode(), p.firstChild);
});
```

This way the text itself is present in the DOM, unlike generated content from CSS.

Comment: Sadly I need the word outside the DOM. If is present in the HTML it breaks another features of the website.

Comment: Calling something which breaks if some word is present in the DOM a "feature" is being quite generous.