# CSS - Selectable ::after pasedo-element

Tags: html, css

I have got an element with ::after pseudo-element:

```css
#someId::after {
  content: 'B';
}
```

```html
<span id="someId">
A
</span>
```

And I can't select secound letter of this `span` ("B"). Can I do something with this `span` so that I can select both of letters? (secound letter must be in ::after)
Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you trying to target the `::after` in this instance? If so, from what I have read before, it's not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735267/can-i-target-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-with-a-sibling-combinator

Comment: No, i am trying to select it with mouse (like normal text)

Comment: Is not possible ... refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/q/27392228/2894798