# How to let user copy CSS ::before content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Text inserted via `::before` and `::after` cannot be selected and not copied.

How can I change this?

```css
span::before {
  content: "including this text";
}
```

```html
<p>
  If the text of this paragraph is selected and copied then all of it should be copied
  <span>instead of only this part</span>.
</p>
```

Using JavaScript instead of CSS is not acceptable. But the following JavaScript would be a acceptable:

1. a function taking an element and returning the `::before` text.
2. a function taking an element and sitting its `:: before` text to `display:none`.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392228/select-text-in-before-or-after-pseudo-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a function taking an element and returning the ::before text.

```
function getPseudoElementContent(selector){
     return window.getComputedStyle(
         selector, ':after'
  );
 }
```

a function taking an element and sitting its :: before text to display:none
`enter code here`

```
 function setPseudoElementContent(selector){
   selector.classList.add("customBefore")
 }
  // And add in your style 
  .customBefore::before{
      content:"" !important;
  }
```